# WYSIWYG/PageDown hybrid?

Tags: forms, web-applications, wysiwyg, markdown, pagedown

I like the idea of using pagedown in my application to prevent forms from saving markup, but I don't like the idea of burdening the users with a learning curve.  What I'd like is an editor like stackoverflow's pagedown that - instead of offering a box to type input and a box to view results - combines markdown editing and results into the same box, like a WYSIWYG editor.  Is there anything like this out there?

Comment: Is this sort of what you were after? https://github.com/will-hart/demarcate.js

Answer (score 0):

This is the markdown editor that stackoverflow use.

[https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/][1]

We have used it before and its very good.